# URL is broken in Apache HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a problem where all the links in my site are broken when the site is in https. Anyway what I need to do is redirect all request from `http` to `https` so I added the code below in `.htaccess`.

```
# Redirect from http to https.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project-local\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://project-local.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Redirection is working fine but what happen if I click any link in the site while it is in https all response is 404.

This is my ssl vhost looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName project-local.com
        DocumentRoot /home/snake/repo/project-a/docroot

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project-a-ssl_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project-a-ssl_access.log common
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/snake/repo/project-a/docroot/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `http->https` rule isn't correct and it can cause infinite redirections, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project-local\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I modified the rule based on your answer but still having 404.

Comment: Oh and another thing the site layout is broken as well. CSS files missing.

Comment: That URL is correctly redirected to https. Are you sure `DocumentRoot` shown in question for SSL is same as that of non-SSL site?

Comment: @anubhava....yes Sir I am sure that `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` are both the same on http and https vhosts.

Comment: In that case why is it 404? This redirect is for `http->https` redirection and that is happening correctly. You can even rename this .htaccess and or comment out this suggested rule and directly `https://project-local.com/about-us`. and see if page opens up correctly.

Comment: After clearing browser cache the 404 problem is now gone. The only remaining issue I have right now is asset like css is not loaded thats why the page is broken. Thanks anubhava. I can now accept this answer.

Comment: Actually CSS/js should also work just make sure they are also available inside SSL site itself.